# Tags That Will Operate As Multiple Tags

Tags: html, tags

I had a very hard time trying to word what I wish to know how to do, nor could I locate any post or website from Google that had my answer probably due to not being able to word this correctly, but I will explain in fullest detail.

```
<br />
<hr />
<br />
```

Break, horizontal, break is my way of separating parts of the post from another. How can I group the three into one simple tag that can replace the three, thus saving me time and hassle .

It would be also helpful to know if there are ways to define tag groupings with more than just empty tags like a tag identified by the string title1 would be a tag containing all **the format, text, and all sub-elements** of the template that was coded somewhere else.

If this question has already been posted then I am sorry. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use `<hr/>`, with the right CSS to add the spacing/margin you want around it?

Comment: I can't remember the name and can't find it, but there **is** a featured being discussed for future inclusion in HTML5 that would let you do what you've literally asked for (define one tag as equivalent to multiple tags).

Comment: @Mat That is a good idea. Thanks! I still want to know about grouping larger sets of html tags and content into a custom tag though.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - You may be thinking of [Data Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/interactive-elements.html#datatemplate), which were dropped from the HTML5 draft around late 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `<br>` tags because `<hr>` is a block level element and automatically creates a line break. If you're doing that to get some vertical space above and below thw `<hr>` why not just use CSS to give the `<hr>` some margin?

```
hr
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That is a great and simple solution to my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `<br>` nor the proposed alternative `<hr>` are particularly well-suited here.

You need to learn about [**CSS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). All you need to do is apply appropriate styles (i.e. a margin) to the elements that wrap your posts.

```
<div class="post">
    <h1>Post #1</h1>
    <p>something</p>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <h1>Post #2</h1>
    <p>something else</p>
</div>
```

```
div.post {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

If you are using [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) then use [`<article>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) instead of `<div class="post">` to denote individual posts.

As for grouping tags, this is currently not possible in plain HTML, you need to apply some preprocessing for that. The usual solution is to use a content management system which creates the final HTML based on your content and an HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this specific problem can be solved with a little bit of CSS, it sounds like you need a layout or templating engine of some sort in the long run. I'm a rubyist by trade so my go-to solution for doing this is [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll).

What Jekyll does is generate static html files from layouts and content that you write. You can abstract a lot of the repetitive layout markup into separate files and then just reference them when you need them.

The following guide is a good place to get started: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-static-sites-with-jekyll/

If you're already working with another framework then do some reading around it first to see if there's something there you can use. If you're just writing straight-up HTML/CSS though, then definitely give Jekyll a try.

Comment: +1 for Jekyll but it sounds as if the OP first needs to learn a lot more about HTML and CSS.

Comment: Is Jerkll an easy to use service/program?